# LWC to display salesforce objects as a picklist onclick

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have a requirement where I need to display list of salesforce objects as a picklist when a radio button is clicked.

Being new to LWC development, I could not figure out what is the right approach to do so. I have come across [this code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QWa-zfwxW/60/edit) from Salesforce articles where we can display radio buttons but as per my scenario, i need to display list of all salesforce objects as picklist when a radio button option is selected.

Can anyone please suggest the right approach to do so.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter in your own implementation process. For more about our format, please take the [Tour] and read [ask]. Please [edit] your question to show us *what you've tried* and *where you are stuck*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a list as searchable list and make a selection onclick](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305367/how-to-make-a-list-as-searchable-list-and-make-a-selection-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an AuraEnabled class that returns list of sObjects. And onclick or most probably onchange of your radio button should call that apex method so that you can use the response list as a picklist valueSet.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, String> getSObjects() {        
        Map<String, String> sObjectNamebyLabel = new Map<String, String>();
        for(SObjectType objectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()) {
            DescribeSObjectResult sObjectDescribe = objectType.getDescribe();
            if(sObjectDescribe.isAccessible() && sObjectDescribe.isQueryable()) {
                sObjectNamebyLabel.put(sObjectDescribe.getLabel(),sObjectDescribe.getName());
            }
        }        
        return sObjectNamebyLabel;
    }
```

on the lwc JS side you can call getSObjectOptions whenever or where ever you want to

```
getSObjectOptions() {
        getSObjects()
            .then((response) => {
                // assign to your picklist or lookup value set
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // toast your error
            });
    }
```

If I were you I would use dynamic lookup component instead of a picklist. There will be a lot of sObject and picklist is not the right element type to display that amount of options. Check below git repo for custom lwc lookup.

https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

Comment: In the future, please use the `{}` button to format the code as code blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: @Mert YALTI, when I'm trying to save the js of LWC, it is not getting saved. Do i need to create an aura component as a parent component here? Please suggest