# How to make a list as searchable list and make a selection onclick

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have a requirement where I need to search for list of items in a lwc and make a selection when clicked on a row.

Below is the thing that I've achieved so far.

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class LwcMapIterationController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static map<string, string> getAllObjects(){
        map<string, string> objectList = new map<string, string>();
        for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
        {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
            objectList.put(objResult.getName(), objResult.getLabel());
        }
        return objectList;
    } 
}
```

LWC HTML:

```
<template>
    <br>
    <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Operation</p>
            <lightning-radio-group name="Operation"

                                   options={options}
                                   value={value}
                                   type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
<br>

        <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Objects</p>
                <div slot="footer">

                </div>
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">

                        <th scope="col">
                            <div title="Key">Object Name (Key)</div>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <template for:each={mapData} for:item="mapKey">
                        <tr key={mapKey.key}>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div title={mapKey.key}>{mapKey.key}</div>
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
</template>
```

LWC .js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchMapData from '@salesforce/apex/LwcMapIterationController.getAllObjects';


export default class LwcMapIteration extends LightningElement {
    value = '';

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Insert', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'Update', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }
    @track mapData= [];

    @wire(fetchMapData)
    wiredResult(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            //mapData = [];
            var conts = result.data;
            for(var key in conts){
                this.mapData.push({value:conts[key], key:key}); //Here we are creating the array to show on UI.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of my output:

[image: List]

Now in my **objects** section, i need to wrap the list in a small list along with a search box. When any object name is searched in the search area/box, the related object needs to be displayed below and onclick,  a selection has to be made.

Can anyone please suggest me the possible solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom lookup component for that, I used below component several times and it worked perfectly well for me.

https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

Comment: The solution given in the link is related to SFDX and mine is not a sfdx org. Wondering how to get this done from the given link. Please suggest

Comment: SFDX is a format. You can clone the repo and convert it to mdAPI format if you want to or you can get the component source files from the repo and apply manually.

Comment: how to execute search query to return only object names instead of object field values. This is from "SampleLookupController" in the given link. Please suggest

Comment: When I did something similar I created a mode variable to keep the existing lookup as it is and also apply some modifications. when needed.

const modes = {
        FIND: 'findRecords',
        LIST: 'listValues'
    };

also an api param for holding values to display.
@api valueMap;

when the type is list I use that map as my value set and I applied my own custom code for the on change action again with separated mode path.